Can't find font in local texmf folder
I have a local texmf tree in my repository for my custom packages. I added this tree to the TEXMFLOCAL variable and I am able to use the packages I placed there. Now, I am also interested in placing a custom font in this tree. The font is called Assistant, but it's also installed on my system, so to verify that the compiler picks up my local font files instead of the installed ones, I changed all their names to Assistante. According to this question, I put my local texmf structure:

I am successfully able to use the my-style package which also loads this font using this code (with babel):
\RequirePackage[bidi=basic, layout=tabular, headfoot=hebrew]{babel}

\babelprovide[main, import, alph=letters, Alph=letters]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import]{english}

\babelfont{assis}{Assistante}

\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{Assistante}
\babelfont[hebrew]{sf}{Assistante}

However, any test code I have doesn't compile complaining it can't find the font Assistante. When I ran kpsewhich Assistante-Regular.ttf I got the correct path, so latex is aware of these font files, but doesn't pick them up. Changing the package code to use Assistant does pick up the font that's installed on my system and works fine. The Assistante.fontspec file:
\defaultfontfeatures[Assistante]
{
    Renderer = HarfBuzz,
    UprightFont = *-Regular,
    BoldFont = *-Bold,
    ItalicFont = *-Regular,
    ItalicFeatures = {FakeSlant = 0.3}
}

I can't understand what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help me fix this or provide an example on how to use a font from a local texmf tree?

you are calling the font by font name and not by file name, and the internal fontname didn't change.

Do you mean the file itself has the name embedded into it? How can I verify that it uses my local file and not the system-installed one? I don't want to go through the trouble of uninstalling my font to test that the local copy works and then reinstalling it.

Yes. The name is embedded into the font. You can specify the font by filename, but sometimes using name versus filename or filename versus name makes a difference. otfinfo -i tells you the font name etc.

if you use lualatex it shows the full path to all included fonts at the end of the log

Found the solution thanks to the comments. Turns out that the idea of renaming the files to prevent the compiler from picking up the font installed on the system was a bad idea. The names are embedded into the files, so renaming them wouldn't be enough. I checked the log file instead and it confirmed that the correct font files are used. Thanks for all the comments.
